# n-dimensional recursion

Tags: differential-equations, recursion, iteration

I am trying to set up a recursive function that generates `n` number of differential equations for `Subscript[y, n][t]`

This function *almost* works.

```
Table[{Subscript[y0, j] = 1}, {j, 50}];(*initial conditions for Subscript[y, n] assuming n<=50*)
vars[n_] := {x, Table[Subscript[y, j], {j, n}]};
sol[0][T_, b_, d_, r_, n_] := 
 sol[0][T, b, d, r, n] = 
  Flatten[vars[n]] /. 
   NDSolve[Flatten@{Join[{x'[t] == 
          10^7 r - d x[t] - b*x[t]*(Sum[Subscript[y, k][t], {k, n}])},
         Table[Subscript[y, j]'[t] == -d Subscript[y, j][t] + 
           b x[t]*Subscript[y, j][t], {j, n}], 
        Flatten[Join[{x[0] == 0}, 
          Flatten[Table[{Subscript[y, j][0] == Subscript[y0, j]}, {j, 
             n}]]]]]}, Flatten[vars[n]], {t, 0, T}][[1]]
sol[i][T_, b_, d_, r_, n_] := 
 sol[i][T, b, d, r, n] = 
  Flatten[vars[n]] /. 
   NDSolve[Flatten@{Join[{x'[t] == 
          10^7 r - d x[t] - b*x[t]*(Sum[Subscript[y, k][t], {k, n}])},
         Table[Subscript[y, j]'[t] == -d Subscript[y, j][t] + 
           b x[t]*Subscript[y, j][t], {j, n}], 
        Flatten[Join[{x[0] == 0},(*next bit seems to be the problem*)
          Flatten[Table[{Subscript[y, j][0] == 
              sol[i - 1][T, b, d, r, n][[j + 1]][T]}, {j, n}]]]]]}, 
     Flatten[vars[n]], {t, 0, T}][[1]]
```

The initial condition `sol[0][T, b, d, r, n]` works as expected and returns the interpolating functions:

```
T = 4; b = 10^-7; d = 0.25; r = 0.2; n = 4;
sol[0][T, b, d, r, n]
```

And also returns the value at `t = T` e.g.
`sol[0][T,  b, d, r, n][[2]][4]`

`sol[i][T, b, d, r, n]`  does not work for `i>0`.

It seems that the problem is where the solution from the previous iteration `i-1` is used to set the initial conditions for current iterate `i`, as marked in the code.

I imagine this will be trivial to troubleshoot for someone on here. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, since you’re not going to use that `Table`, you can use `Do` instead: `Do[Subscript[y0, j] = 1;, {j, 50}]` Not really important here since there are only 50, but good practice in general so you don’t take up memory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very small error, but posting this as an answer so the question can be marked as resolved:

In defining the recursive version of `sol`, you wrote `sol[i][T_, b_, d_, r_, n_] := (...)` instead of `sol[i_][T_, b_, d_, r_, n_] := (...)`! That is, adding an underscore to that first occurrence of `i` seems to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it!